# Install Drupal via Drush without using browser

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, chef-infra, drush

Here's my situation. I'm trying to use Chef to install a drupal site (purely automated, no human input). So far I have been able to use drush to install drupal7.

Once I have all the drupal files in my document root folder, it seems that I need to physically go to the browser and complete the install script on the website. If I don't, the drush site-install created the drupal db, but it has no tables.

Surely there must be a way to more or less follow the install script on the website through the drush command line? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if there is anything I can clarify. The container with drupal is on Ubuntu 14.04, I am using Drush 7.* and want to install Drupal 7.x.

Comment: Do you really need to install it there? Maybe you can install it manually at some other server, zip the files dump the database and at your "purely automated" server just unpack it and import db dump?

Comment: take a look http://www.coderintherye.com/install-drupal-7-using-drush

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what arguments you're passing to drush site-install, it's hard to figure out where the problem is. This answer assumes that you're running MySQL

Assuming you're running a command that looks like so:

```
drush si standard --db-url=mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@localhost:port/dbname 
--db-su=name --db-su-pw=password --site-name="Your New Site"
```

If tables aren't being created, I'd first make sure that the mysql user you're running as has create table permissions for that database. An easy way to root out whether it's a permission issue would be to use root username and password details.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, enable your database's logging to see if create table commands are being issued by drush.

Hope this helps

Comment: If this worked for you, I'd really appreciate an up-vote